# How would I load RGBA image data from bitmap files without the use of libraries

Tags: c++, image

I would like to learn how to load image data in the form of RGBA (8 bits per channel) for opengl from bitmap files without using a library (so no soil or stb_image which i'm already using and would like to replace)

I do not know where to begin. Please can you help me out? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: You would then basically have to re-implement the library. Why bother? Why not just use the, already written, library?

Answer (score 1):

Good way would be to study those libraries as they are both open-source. So go read through their code and try to understand it.

If you want to do it yourself you have to first lookup the file formats of the images you want to load e.g [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). Then the image loading is *just* reading the binary files byte by byte and interpreting those bytes correctly.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows you do not need any library to load a BMP file since that functionality is built in to the operating system. You can use the [LoadImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) function.